# Replacing specific Gutenberg blocks

Tags: hooks, block-editor

I was wondering if there is any way to: replace a Gutenberg block (in this case the navigation), with ESI, + fetch this block in another endpoint the ESI tag points to.
In classic themes this is fairly easy because you can get nav + id.

Haven't found something like this with blocks (render_block contains a reference like `core/navigation` but it isn't unique).

Comment: What is ESI? Edge side includes?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure If I get what you meant, but `study https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/render_block_this-name/` filter, whan calling it give it $accepted_args number of 3 and inspect what is returned in $block_content or $instance. ID is encoded as ref attribute, if that's what you are missing.

You could also use `render_block` filter, but `render_block_{$this->name}` is more convenient, since it is called just for block type specified in filter name.